# How to get Object value from message payload in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

As show below I have configured spliter and in input-channel value will be generic message of spring integration

Generic message

```
Map<String,Object> payload;
    values are   
      serviceRequest=Some Object
      messageBusmessages= Some Object 

MessageHeaders headers;
```

Now my requirement is like I want to get value from payload which is map by key and put one in messagebus.channel and other in servicebody.channel

```
<int:splitter input-channel="outChannel"
    output-channel="messagebus.channel">
</int:splitter>

<int:splitter input-channel="outChannel"
    output-channel="servicebody.channel">
</int:splitter>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using expression we can get object from payload map and put into channels as required below option works for me.

```
<int:splitter input-channel="outChannel" expression="payload.get('messagebusMesssages')"
    output-channel="message.channel">
</int:splitter>

<int:splitter input-channel="outChannel" expression="payload.get('serviceRequest')"
    output-channel="servicebody.channel">
</int:splitter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="servicebody.channel"
    ref="SITestAction" method="action" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to split, I think you need content based routing. If you can, add something to the incoming header of the message and use an out of the box spring integration header-value-router.

```
<header-value-router input-channel="routingChannel" header-name="testHeader">
  <mapping value="serviceRequest" channel="messagebus.channel" />
  <mapping value="messageBusmessages" channel="servicebody.channel" />
</header-value-router>
```

If this doesn't suit you needs. have a look here at the link below and see all the options Spring Integration has for routing.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html

Comment: As per our requirement we don't want to add any thing in header. And as mentioned above at that point I have already applied my transformer and in outChannel I will receive GenericMessage object and in GenericMessage payload I have messageBus messages and serviceRequest Object I just want de composite payload in to channel that's why I am using splitter

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to do a split and a route. Splitters by nature, split the message up but they doesn't re-route based on content, I think this is where you are getting confused. So then I suggest you use Gary Russell option or write a splitter followed by a router in the flow where you can redirect it to the correct channel. Here is an example of a router where you can on basis of payload attributes determine which channel the message should be directed to. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9781449335403/routers/id2863549

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` with 2 subscribers which are `<transformer/>`s with appropriate expressions...

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="outChannel"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="outChannel" outputChannel="messagebus.channel"
    expression="payload.['foo']"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="outChannel" outputChannel="servicebody.channel"
    expression="payload.['bar']"/>
```

This will process serially; if you want them to run in parallel, put a `task-executor` on the `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`.